# Can't see boost::optional contents when debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-optional

If I try to look at the variable directly, I see a `?` sign. If I create a watch calling the `is_initialized` function, I get the following error:

> CXX0033: Error: error in OMF type information

I didn't find much info about this error related to Boost using Google.

Anybody else experienced this? It's a hassle using `OutputDebugString` everywhere and rebuilding...

**EDIT**: Using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with all hotfixes in Windows XP SP3 idem, and Boost 1.49.0

**UPDATE**: This issue comes and goes, it doesn't happen consistently; Debugger Visualizers are a great solution, I've adopted them as my brand new tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [DebuggerVisualizers](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers).

Answer (score 7):

Use [DebuggerVisualizers](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers) to make this transition:

**Before**

[image: ludicrously complicated]

**After**

[image: simple]

P.S. I tried to add these images to clarify the accepted answer but my edit was rejected.

Answer (score 6):

Try this: for a variable `boost::optional<Category> category`, create a watch on: `category.get()`

Comment: In VS 2005 I get CXX0039: Error: symbol is ambiguous